# Prove that a function is a solution of the differential equation

Tags: functions, differential

I would like to ask for some hint to the following problem :

Let $y(t,\alpha)$ be the solution of the system :

$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
Lx=0 \\ x(\alpha)=x'(\alpha)=\cdots=x^{(n-1)}(\alpha)=0, x^{(n)}(\alpha)=1
\end{array} \right.$$

Prove that $\phi $(t) = $\int_{t_0}^t y(t,\alpha) f(\alpha) \, d\alpha $ is the solution of :

$$
 \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
Lx=f \\ \phi(t_0)=\phi'(t_0)=\cdots=\phi^{(n-1)}(t_0)=0
\end{array} \right.$$